# How can I get YouTube playlist views count?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does anyone know how this [website](https://chartex.com/playlist-statistics/youtube/1-4468) is able to get historical views data for YouTube playlists?
From my research, YouTube API doesn't even let you get the current playlist views (I might be wrong).

I am talking about the playlist views, not the views from videos that were added to the playlist (you can see the view count [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbpi6ZahtOH7eFIp5Cc15AnhiIdkjgmdC) for example, on the left side - on desktop).

How can we get access to this type of data?

Answer (score 2):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 [doesn't provide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource) a basic feature.

I would recommend you to use my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0f27d62fcb2813a1a5f8a55fc2597f0090af4006/playlists.php#L34) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/). Indeed by requesting the JSON document https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlists?part=statistics&id=PLAYLIST_ID containing `item["statistics"]["viewCount"]` integer, your problem is solved.

You can request up to `maxResults` (currently 50) playlists separating playlist ids by a comma in id, example: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlists?part=statistics&id=PLAYLIST_ID_0,PLAYLIST_ID_1,...,PLAYLIST_ID_49

You can also request the title of the playlist by adding `snippet` to `part`, example: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/playlists?part=snippet,statistics&id=PLAYLIST_ID

Comment: Hi Ben, this is very useful. I'm not very code-savvy, but is it possible to input multiple IDs and get back the view count for all of them? Maybe even exported in an excel sheet if that's not too much. It would also be useful to include the playlist title in the JSON document, I'm not sure if that's possible. Is there a way to use my own API key, I see that there is a "PAGE_TOKEN" variable, but I'm not sure what that is exactly. I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: I edited my answer to answer some of your questions, for the others:
The CSV export is your job, not mine since JSON is a plaintext format.
There is no need of your API key (my API doesn't use YouTube Data API v3).
There isn't any mention of a `PAGE_TOKEN` for the Playlists endpoint I mentioned.